# Why does "date" show different times in root and user?

Tags: debian, date, raspbian, timezone

Using `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` I have set my timezone to CST, but for non root users the system persists in using UTC time.

```
pi@raspberry ~ $ date
Wed Oct 28 18:14:08 UTC 2015

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# date
Wed Oct 28 12:14:08 CST 2015
```

The problem is also evident in LXPanel Digital Clock and timestamps in Epiphany web pages.

How can I force system time not to use UTC but to use the timezone time I set with tzdata, which is CST?

Comment: is there any evidence that the non-root user's login scripts are setting TZ themselves? `grep TZ ~/.[a-z]*` (for example)

Comment: What does `echo $TZ` say when run as each user?

Comment: UTC is often a better option for systems, as it doesn't have the stupidity of doubled or eliminated hours thanks to Daylight Saving Time. Are you really sure you need a local timezone that may cause errors or lost data twice per year?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Time Zone in the recommended way i.e. raspi-config?

Comment: All raspi-config does is run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the command:
`tzconfig`

Also check you environmental variables for the non root user:
`echo $TZ`

In case is different to the desired, edit the file where is defined that variable, could be one of these:

```
$HOME/.bash_profile
$HOME/.profile
$HOME/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed this in RHEL7 for a user who had the UTC time set correctly, but didn't apply the CEST part. The fix was changing the permissions to /etc/localtime from `600` to `644` so that other users apart from root could use it. Therefore, something like:

```
chmod 0644 /etc/localtime
```

should to the trick, if that was your problem.

Here is the relevant article from Redhat:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2428001

Comment: Is that RedHat that sets those 0600 incorrect permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. It's probably a mix of using system tools and editing files manually that doesn't gel properly, but again, not sure